# Having trouble with Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk

About half the time this works, and the other half it does not. By "work", I mean that people claim to be just "logged out" of Facebook and nothing happens thereafter – i.e., they are likely redirected back to my `/index` page.

My goal is very simple: If the user is logged in to or out of Facebook, log them out and provide them the option to sign in with their credentials. Assuming they sign in successfully, I perform the _login function, where I redirect them to my `/auth/fb/<verification code>/` handler. This handler adds the new user to my database.

I don't want to "assume" they are logged in or out of Facebook when they perform this sign up, so like I said above, I need them to be presented with the FB JS auth dialogue.

I am very new to using Javascript, let alone with the FB SDK, so please bear with me on this so I can improve. Thank you.

My full JS code for using the api is this:

```
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into Facebook
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        //console.log("not auth");
    } else {
        // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
        // they are logged into this app or not.
    }
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<my_appid>',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        oauth      : true,
        version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

    button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
    button.onclick = function(response) {

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // Handle the response object, like in statusChangeCallback() in our demo code.
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                _login();
            });
        });
    };
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=<my_appid>&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function _login() {
    window.location = "/auth/login/fb/" + _getVerificationCode() + "/";
}

function _logout(response) {
    FB.logout(function(response){});
}

function _getVerificationCode() {
    var vc = document.getElementById('verificationCode');
    if (vc !== null) {
        return vc.value;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: proper way to add an event listener in javascript: element.addEventListener('click', callback, false);

Comment: Would you mind clarifying where exactly would you make this change in the above code?

Comment: because it is the modern way, and onclick overrides any previous listener. better: addEventListener and removeEventListener, with full control on your own.